# React Component not rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, render, router

I have an issue with my "Home" react component.

I am using react-router, and have a route file that contains the following:

```
 <Router history={ browserHistory }>
      <Route path="/" component={ App }>
        <IndexRoute component={ Home } />
      </Route>
    </Router>
```

Now, my Home component works when defined like this:

```
export const Home = () => <h3>Index</h3>;
```

But if I defined it like this:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <h3>InDex2</h3>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Then it is not working. Nothing gets rendered in the second case, while in the first case I can see 'Index'...

Do you have an idea why this is not working?

My App component is as simple as this:

```
export const App = ( { children } ) => (
  <div>
    <AppNavigation />
    { children }
    <Alert stack={{limit: 3}} />
  </div>
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if that's the case.

Answer (score 6):

To import your first component, you need to take the named export `Home`:

```
// Home.js
export const Home = () => <h3>Index</h3>;

// someOtherFile.js
import { Home } from './Home';
```

In your second case, you need to take the `default` export:

```
// someOtherFile.js
import Home from './Home';
```

Comment: Thanks. I was taking the { Home} component and therefore it was not working. Do you have a best practice to follow with regards to the use of "default" ?

Comment: @user3900157 No problem. If you are just exporting a single thing from a file, I think it is nice to use `default`.

Comment: I always forget to export.